# MSVC - do not display compiler version/copyright information

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, nmake, cl.exe

I have a makefile:

```
all: hello.cpp
    cl /EHsc hello.cpp
```

In developer powershell when I type `nmake` I get:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.28.29915.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cl /EHsc hello.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29915 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

hello.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29915.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:hello.exe
hello.obj
```

Is there a way to not display

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29915 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

and

```
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29915.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

but just display

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.28.29915.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cl /EHsc hello.cpp

hello.cpp
/out:hello.exe
hello.obj
```

or something similar. I just want the microsoft banners to not be displayed as they take up unnecessary lines.

Comment: why do you want to show the command usage in makefile? It's only for humans to read. In scripts you'd want to get things like error output and compiling result

Comment: @Sajeeb Lookup [`/nologo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/nologo-suppress-startup-banner-c-cpp?view=msvc-160).

Comment: Thanks @dxiv that was what I was looking for. I must have missed it when reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-by-category?view=msvc-160

Comment: `cl /?` gives all the options, including `/nologo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by [@dxiv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5538420/dxiv) in the comments, adding `/nologo` flag seems to have worked. The modified makefile is:

```
all: hello.cpp
    cl /EHsc /nologo hello.cpp
```

The output on the developer powershell is:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.28.29915.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cl /EHsc /nologo hello.cpp
hello.cpp
```

I don't know why does microsoft feel the need to display this (compiler version and copyright information) information by default as it is completely unnecessary. If I need the compiler version for debugging I should be able to do something like `cl -v` similar to `g++` for UNIX. More flags can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-by-category?view=msvc-160).

Comment: *I don't know why does microsoft feel the need to display...* - Probably completely historical and for backwards compat.  But when you are debugging long build output logs, sometimes those markers can be very useful.  For what it's worth, Visual Studio projects default to having `/nologo` specified.

Comment: "The output on the developer powershell is:" -- Use `nmake /nologo` instead of `nmake`. Or write a file "make.ps1" with the content `nmake /nologo` and start this PowerShell script instead of `nmake`. You could also define a PowerShell function to invoke `nmake` with that parameter.